# Failed to contact Google map servers

Tags: android, google-maps

I know this has been asked and answered many times but despite following lots of solutions on here I still can't get past this error:
 `Failed to load map. Could not contact Google servers`

I've set "Google Maps Android API v2" and deleted then regenerated the debug.keystore before trying with a new key but no further forward.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

My `activity_main.xml`:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:cameraTilt="45"
    map:cameraZoom="14"
/>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.abelsoul.androidmapproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
android:name="com.abelsoul.androidmapproject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.abelsoul.androidmapproject.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application        
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.abelsoul.androidmapproject.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />        
</application>
</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.abelsoul.androidmapproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: all i can see is different from my code is i have xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" im not even sure if thats necesarry in your xml

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding that but same result.

Comment: i had that error a couple times 1 time was because on the google play services console my package name was wrong with key, and another time because i checked google maps api v2 and not google maps android api v2, im not 100% but it may be a google play services console thing because i think your code looks fine, thats what the error was for me both times

Comment: Have you referenced the Google Play Services library in your project?

Comment: <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> im not sure if i left it in from maps v1 or if its a v2 thing, its still in my manifest though and its running fine on the market

Comment: @JRowan No _<uses-library ... />_ thing is needed.

Comment: @Zabri, thanks, hey maybe that was it, lets wait and find out :)

Comment: @JRowan, no it not, it's a Google Map API V1 permission, and not needed in API V2. the code look fine. There must be something you are doing wrong with generating or registering you SHA1 key.

Comment: @Zabri: Yes, GPS library imported and referenced.

Comment: if somebody still looking for an answer, check here - the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17947755/1891118

Answer (score 2):

If you use WIFI instead of a 3G data plan, maybe you need add the permission to access wifi state, such as

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

into your manifest file. This line fixed my issue.